# Regular expression to fetch in multiple lines

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Thanks in advance, i've this problem, my regular expression is this:

```
    <title>(.*?)<\/title>
```

And works for those:

```
    <title>Sapateira l Mais de 80 itens | Mobly</title>
    <title>Sapateiras - Móveis e Decoração ‹ Magazine Luiza</title>
    <title>Sapateira l Mais de 80 itens | Mobly</title>
```

And doesn't for that:

```
    <title>
        Sapateiras em Promoção | Preço de Dormitórios / Quartos | CasasBahia.com.br| Dia do Consumidor 2016
    </title>
```

Comment: You need to use multiline regexes

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<title>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/title>
```

`\s` matches any whitespace character (spaces, tabs and line breaks)

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to include newline characters in your regex.  Something like this would work:

```
<title>\n*(.*?)\n*\s*<\/title>
```

Regex example:
https://regex101.com/r/kR2xM7/1

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
/<title>(.|\r|\n)*?<\/title>/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/wN8dS7/1

Answer (score 0):

You can do so in PHP with this regex:

```
preg_match('%<title>[\s\S]+?</title>%im', $subject, $regs)
```

> Javascript:

```
var myregexp = /<title>[\s\S]+?<\/title>/im;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
```